# How to give a common type when a function is called from different components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

I working in react typescript. I have created a common utility function like this -

```
interface IUpdatedRows {
  rowsPerPage: number;

  // this is where the confusion is - 
  rows: {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    description: string;
    role: string;
    manager: string;
    total_tasks: number;
    annotator: number;
    qc: number; }[];
  //

  page: number;
}

export const updatedRows = (args: IUpdatedRows) => (args.rowsPerPage > 0
  ? args.rows.slice(args.page * args.rowsPerPage, args.page * args.rowsPerPage + args.rowsPerPage)
  : args.rows
);
```

Here I will use updatedRows function from separate components having different set of rows. Above situation works well only for 1 component where row have exactly the type I have mentioned above i.e.

```
row: {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    description: string;
    role: string;
    manager: string;
    total_tasks: number;
    annotator: number;
    qc: number; }[];
```

In a different component row have these fields -

```
row: {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    code: string;
    type: string;
    added_by: string;
    added_on: string;
  };
```

I am not sure how to give a common type in a utility file for `row` which will be applicable for all the components. Any help, pointers is highly appreciated.

Comment: You can make `IUpdatedRows<T>` generic with rows: T[] or any of its variations.

Comment: hey @SergeySosunov, can you throw more light on it as I am new to typescript and not have much idea around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asuming `IUpdatedRows` interface itself and the related function `updatedRows` does not need to know anything about the type of Rows (except the fact that is should be an array) and they should be used for different types of Rows - you can use [Generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html).

```ts
interface IUpdatedRows<T> {
  rowsPerPage: number;
  rows: T[];
  page: number;
}

export const updatedRows = <T,>(args: IUpdatedRows<T>) => (args.rowsPerPage > 0
  ? args.rows.slice(args.page * args.rowsPerPage, args.page * args.rowsPerPage + args.rowsPerPage)
  : args.rows
);

interface IComponent1Row{
    id: number;
    qc: number;
    // ...rest
}

interface IComponent2Row{
    id: number;
    name: string;
    // ...rest
}

const rows1: IComponent1Row[] = [];
const rows2: IComponent2Row[] = [];

const updateRows1: IUpdatedRows<IComponent1Row> = {
    page: 1,
    rows: rows1,
    rowsPerPage: 10
}

const updateRows2: IUpdatedRows<IComponent2Row> = {
    page: 1,
    rows: rows2,
    rowsPerPage: 20
}

const updateRows1Result: IComponent1Row[] = updatedRows(updateRows1);
const updateRows2Result: IComponent2Row[] = updatedRows(updateRows2);
```

Link to the playground: [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-OWPewzmtGK6M+7PQRc-nC6LkSXJWWfUqq832Ei1kA)